# Laravel polymorphic relation in Nova

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

My current blog like app has a `Page` that could have many `Paragraphs` of a different structure (Text, Image, File download, Registration form, ... ). When trying to translate this to Eloquent Models with relations, I think this is an easy way to do so:

Table `pages`:

- id
- title, ...

Table `paragraphs`:

- id
- page_id
- paragraphable_id
- paragraphable_type

Table `paragraph_texts`:

- id
- text

Table `paragraph_images`:

- id
- image_path

Table `paragraph_downloads`:

- id
- file_path

And the Models:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{

    public function paragraphs() {
        return $this->hasMany(Paragraph::class);
    }
}

?>
```

The Paragraph Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Paragraph extends Model
{
    public $table = 'paragraphs';
    public $timestamps = [];

    public function page() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
    }

    public function paragraphable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

The Text Type model as sample:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models\ParagraphTypes;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Text extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'paragraph_texts';

    public function paragraph() {
        return $this->morphOne(Paragraph::class, 'paragraphable');
    }

}
```

I now want to view the page in nova and create a new paragraph by a selectable type. I created the Resource classes (for page, for paragraph and for each paragraph type) according to the eloquent relations (HasMany field for the page, MorphTo for the paragraph and just a TextArea for the Text type). When I see the details of a page and want to add a new paragraph, I can see the form to add a paragraph and can select the paragraph type in a dropdown but can only see the already existing entries, not new one. I will never want to add an existing paragraph type like this.

So questions:

- Is the transformation of the structure into eloquent correct, are there any improvements?
- How could laravel nova handle the creation of a new paragraph type for a page "through" the paragraph model? I feel like having to add a custom field to do so, that maybe asks for the type to create first...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question: You should use the relationships from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations):

```php
class Page extends Model
{
    public function texts() {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Text::class, 'paragraphable', 'paragraphs');
    }
}

class Text extends Model
{
    public function pages() {
        return $this->morphToMany(Page::class, 'paragraphable', 'paragraphs');
    }
}
```

You can get multiple paragraph types with an accessor:

```php
class Page extends Model
{
    public function getParagraphsAttribute() {
        return $this->texts->toBase()->merge($this->files)->merge([...]);
    }
}

$paragraphs = $page->paragraphs;
```

Comment: This might be a solution when dealing with the Many To Many "Tags" relation from the docs. But what I want to have here is a single relation to "paragraphs" which each could be of a certain type. Following your example would lead to having a morphedByMany relation for each Paragraphtype in the page model.

Comment: I don't see how your relationship is different from the one in the docs.

Comment: Well not when it stays with only one Paragraph Type like Text. But I'd like to have a single relationship "Paragraph" that defines several Types and a column "sort_order" which defines in which order the paragraphs should be listed on the page. If I have 5 Paragraph types for instance (Text, File, Image, Slideshow, Quiz) I could define 5 relations to the Page model but have no single relation "paragraphs" to access and will loose the sorting.

Comment: There is no (native) relationship that can return multiple paragraph types. The default solution for cases like this is an accessor. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, this seems to be a solution for accessing the paragraph types. But by merging the single relationships, a built in solution seems not be available in laravel and nova.

Comment: I've created a package for merging relationships: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-merged-relations